# Send vars without using input hidden php

Tags: php, forms, input, hidden

I wonder if you could also send vars without using hidden input, because input hidden is always readable in the code

Comment: Use a session, that's what they're for

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You have to pass data somehow, and that data is always readable.

Comment: You want to send variables. Three questions: from where, to where, and why?

Comment: i want to send data from a form to a page that submits it to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_SESSION` or continue using hidden inputs with encrypted name and value, then the user has no clue what they are reading.